# Quarterly datepicker

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I am looking for a Quarterly date picker using ng-bootstrap.

At the moment I have Month and Year see **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-quarterdatepicker-zrkyet)** but I would like to change the Month to Quarter.

[image]

**Is this possible with ng-bootstrap?**

> *For info: here is a previous stackblitz example using **[Angular Material](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-quarter-picker)***
>
> [image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/76Lhvfy0/ this example shows a Quarterly datepicker but unfortunately it is in jQuery @malbarmawi

Comment: I left a work in progress and "as is" in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zuyj77?file=src NOTE: I'll try improve, but I'm not sure when I'll get time for it (and for explain the code). Basically is a ng-dropdown with auto-close="outside". I copy the css for the arrows, good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"briefly" explain about the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zuyj77?file=src)

Basicaly we has a ng-dropDown that show a series of ngbDropdownItem

we has as variables

```
year:number; //the year selected
quarter:string; //hte quarter selected

yearDefault=new Date().getFullYear() //the year by defect
quarterDefault="Q"+(1+Math.floor(new Date().getMonth()/3)) //the quarter by defect

showQuarter:boolean=true; //a boolean variable. 
         //if true, the ngbDropdownItems will be the quarter, 
         //else the years

year10:number; //auxliar for show the list of years
```

And an auxiliar array to show the quarter

```
options: any[] = [
    {value:'Q1',months:['Jan','Feb','Mar']},
    {value:'Q2',months:['Apr','May','Jun']},
    {value:'Q3',months:['Jul','Aug','Sep']},
    {value:'Q4',months:['Oct','Nov','Dec']}
  ];
```

So, in our ngbDropdownMenu we can show

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showQuarter">
    <button [ngClass]="{'bg-primary':item.value==quarter}" ngbDropdownItem 
         *ngFor="let item of options" 
         (click)="click(item.value,drop)">
        <span class="col" *ngFor="let month of item.months" >
           {{month}}
        </span>
    </button>
</ng-container>

//or

<ng-container *ngIf="!showQuarter">
    <button [ngClass]="{'bg-primary':(year10+item)==year}" ngbDropdownItem 
          *ngFor="let item of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]" 
          (click)="changeYear(year10+item);showQuarter=true">
        <span >{{year10+item}}</span>
    </button>
</ng-container>
```

Moreover, we show a "header" with two buttons (left and rigth arrow) and a span that show or the year or the decade

```
<div class="selectYear">
    <div class="ngb-dp-arrow">
        <button  class="btn btn-link ngb-dp-arrow-btn" type="button"
            (click)="showQuarter?changeYear((year||yearDefault)-1):year10=year10-10">
           <span class="ngb-dp-navigation-chevron">
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" (click)="changeShowQuarter()">
        {{showQuarter?year?year:yearDefault:(year10+' - '+(year10+9))}}
    </button>
    
    <div class="ngb-dp-arrow right">
        <button class="btn btn-link ngb-dp-arrow-btn" type="button" 
            (click)="showQuarter?changeYear((year||yearDefault)+1):year10=year10+10">
            <span class="ngb-dp-navigation-chevron">
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

See how, depending the variable "showQuarter" the buttons make one or another action

The functions are simples, again we make take account that at first, year and quarter can has no value, in that case we use yearDefault and QuarterDefault

```
changeYear(year)
  {
    this.year=year || this.yearDefault;
    this.quarter=this.quarter||this.quarterDefault
              this.control.setValue(this.quarter+" "+this.year || this.yearDefault,{emitEvent:false})
  }
  changeShowQuarter()
  {
    this.showQuarter=!this.showQuarter
    if (!this.showQuarter)
      this.year10=this.year?10*Math.floor(this.year/10):10*Math.floor(this.yearDefault/10)
  }
  click(quarter,drop)
  {
    this.quarter=quarter;
    this.year=this.year||this.yearDefault
              this.control.setValue(this.quarter+" "+this.year,{emitEvent:false})
    drop.close()
  }
```

And yes, we has a FormControl called control, becaouse we has an input

```
  <input style="text-transform: uppercase" [formControl]="control" placeholder="Qq yyyy" >
  
  control:FormControl= new FormControl()
```

To control the manually entry of the quarter and year we subscribe to control.valueChanges, to give value to year and quarter only if the length of string is greater or equal to 6

```
this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      takeWhile(()=>this.alive),
      startWith(this.quarter+" "+this.year),
      debounceTime(200))
    .subscribe((res:string)=>{
//      console.log(this.controlID.nativeElement.selectionStart)
       if (res)
       {
         res=res.toUpperCase()
         if (res[0]!="Q")
           res="Q"+res;
           let value=res.replace(/[^Q|0-9]/g, '');
           let quarter;
           let year;
           if (value.length>=2)
              quarter=value[0]+value[1]
           if (value.length>=6)
           {
              year=value.substr(2,4)
              this.year=+year
              this.quarter=quarter;
              this.control.setValue((this.quarter+" "+this.year),{emitEvent:false})
           }
           else
           {
             this.year=null;
             this.quarter=null;
           }
       }
    })
```

TODO: create a custom form control with the component, revised the .css to improve and remove unnecesary styles

**Update** convert in a CustomFormControl it's easy, only implements ControlValueAccessor

```
  disabled: boolean = false;
  onChange: (_: any) => void;
  onTouched: any;

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
  writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (value) {
      this.year = value.year;
      this.quarter = value.quarter;
      if (this.year && this.quarter)
        this.control.setValue(this.quarter + " " + this.year,{emitEvent:false});
    }
  }
```

I use an auxiliar function

```
  setValue(data: any) {
      if (data && data.quarter && data.year) {
        this.control.setValue(data.quarter + " " + data.year, {
          emitEvent: false
        });
        this.onChange({ quarter: data.quarter, year: data.year });
      } else {
        this.control.setValue(data, { emitEvent: false });
        this.onChange(null);
      }
  }
```

That call in control.valueChanges subscribe and in click function

I leave in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxckoy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquarter-picker%2Fquarter-picker.component.ts)

NOTE: like ng-bootstrap I choose that the return value was an object with the properties year and quarter

**Update** @Mohan ask about improve the month date picker adding a minQuarter.

To add a minQuarter and maxQuarter it's "only" add two inputs more

```
@Input() minQuarter={ quarter: "Q1", year: 0 };
@Input() maxQuarter={ quarter: "Q4", year: 9999 }
```

Well, now we need disabled the buttons to take account this values. There are severals buttons and we need take caraful when disabled it

```
//arrow left
[disabled]="minQuarter.year>=(showQuarter?year:year10)"

//arrow right
[disabled]="maxQuarter.year<=(showQuarter?year:(year10+10))" 

//the quarters
[disabled]="(minQuarter.year==year && item.value<minQuarter.quarter) 
          ||(maxQuarter.year==year && item.value>minQuarter.quarter)"

//the years
[disabled]="((year10+item)<minQuarter.year || (year10+item)>maxQuarter.year)"
```

more over, we can take accont when we change manually the quarter, force to get the minQuarter or maxQuarter. So in the subscribe to control.valueChanges,

```
this.control.valueChanges
  .pipe(...)
  .subscribe((res: string) => {
    let quarter = null;
    let year = null;
        ...
    //here check the min and max value
    if (year)
    {
       if (year<this.minQuarter.year)
           year=this.minQuarter.year

       if (year>this.minQuarter.year)
           year=this.maxQuarter.year

       if (year==this.minQuarter.year && quarter<this.minQuarter.quarter)
           quarter=this.minQuarter.quarter;

       if (year==this.maxQuarter.year && quarter>this.minQuarter.quarter)
           quarter=this.maxQuarter.quarter;
    }
    ....
  });
```

}

If I not missed, it's all. I updated the stackblitz

Comment: The above changes are working. Please suggest me how can i disable existing quarter months.
Example: The current month is September 2020. So I should enable only current month quarter (user shouldn't choose previous month quarter).

Comment: I updated the answer and the stackblitz. I think that is yet ok