# How to create a custom fantasy calendar with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm creating a Dungeons and Dragons website and I want to add the ability to have custom months with a custom amount of days and custom weekdays. I have columns in my DB tables for StartWeekday, StartMonth, StartDate, and StartYear. I would like to build my own Date Picker component, but I cannot find anything on how to create a custom calendar using JavaScript.

Comment: This question is probably too broad to be answered here.

Comment: To create a calendar:[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59943990/is-there-any-way-i-can-make-custom-datepicker-without-using-angular-material-or/59945162#59945162). To create a custom form component with a "dropdown":[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73905665/how-to-build-a-colour-pallete-in-dropdown-in-angular/73908751#73908751). To "formatting a input" (it's not the better example) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321546/quarterly-datepicker/58336925#58336925)